# Is it possible to make an object with the follow path constraint stay at the end of the path even if the path moves?

Tags: constraints, path

I tried setting it up so that the object is parented to the path, but that didn't work. It still goes off in a random direction when the path moves.

Comment: it might be what Jackdaw explain, but please show some screenshots of the situation to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are selecting both when you only should move the curve. Select curve only when moving. Otherwise you will get something called *double transformation*, essentially moving it twice getting all kinds of weirdness.